# Thread.Abort() not immedate (WebClient) c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, webclient

I have a piece of code which closes all the threads in a thread list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ThreadList.Count - 1; i++)
{
    ThreadList[i].Abort();
}
```

The issue is that inside the thread code there is a webclient piece of code which can take a while to complete. I realized that I cannot close threads which have running code inside, but if that is the case, how can I close the threads?

Comment: The solution is to use `Task cancellation` or to close the `Thread` and catch the thrown exception. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366959/thread-abort-and-alternatives

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ty8d3wta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx: "The thread is not guaranteed to abort immediately, or at all...."

Comment: Abort the web client, not the thread. `WebRequest.Abort`

Comment: but the webclient is inside the thread,and there are multiple at the same time. how would i do that? :)

Comment: Keep a list of pending requests.

Comment: is there some for of documentation on that?