# Stop C# thread immediately without "Thread.Abort()"

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, abort

```
public class Worker
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private Thread t;

    public Worker()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        t = new Thread(() => { ThreadTask(cts.Token); });
    }

    ~Worker()
    {
        cts.Dispose();
    }

    private void ThreadTask(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Cancelllation requested");
                    break;
                }

                // long task 1
                Debug.WriteLine("Task 1 completed");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                // long task 2
                Debug.WriteLine("Task 2 completed");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                // long task 3
                Debug.WriteLine("Task 3 completed");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                // long task 4
                Debug.WriteLine("Task 4 completed");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Debug.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Thread exception: " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            // cleanup
            Debug.WriteLine("Thread cleanup");
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        t.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to interrupt a thread before it finishes executing.

For example, in code described above, when calling a function `Stop()`, the thread will be stopped when it finishes execution, I would like to stop it more quickly, such as between "long tasks" or even while a `Thread.Sleep(2000)`.

A solution would be to maybe throw an exception in the task thread when calling the `Stop()` like `Thread.Abort()`, but `Thread.Abort()` does not work on Net 6.0, how can I do that?

Environment:

- C#
- Net 6.0
- Windows 10 x64
- Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2022

Comment: You should swap to an async method and use `await Task.Delay(2000, ct);`. However there's no easy way to stop a CPU bound task. The task will need to periodically check for cancellation.

Comment: Put a look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3367689/6539880). Otherwise (AFAIK) you need to implement some kind of cooperation between tasks (cancellation token, coroutine, ...)

Comment: When `Thread.Abort()` was available it was not a solution for your problem. Calling `Abort` was only useful when you were trying to forcibly exit your app, as calling it can corrupt the .NET run-time itself. You could not rely on your program working after calling `Abort`. The only real answer is to have the thread stop itself co-operatively.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. @JeremyLakeman your suggestion was very helpful, I even managed to use it even without a async method with `Task.Delay(2000, ct).Wait()`.

Comment: @PedroDuarte - Please don't `.Wait()` for tasks like that. You should always use `await`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`Thread.Interrupt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.interrupt) method. This API is supported in the current .NET platform.

> Interrupts a thread that is in the `WaitSleepJoin` thread state.
>
> If this thread is not currently blocked in a wait, sleep, or join state, it will be interrupted when it next begins to block.
>
> `ThreadInterruptedException` is thrown in the interrupted thread, but not until the thread blocks. If the thread never blocks, the exception is never thrown, and thus the thread might complete without ever being interrupted.

You'll have to handle a possible `ThreadInterruptedException` inside the body of the `ThreadStart` delegate, otherwise the process may crash when the `Interrupt` is invoked. Or you could just handle all exceptions with a generic `catch (Exception)` handler, as you are currently doing.

Comment: Using `Thread.Interrupt()` is a really good alternative, thanks for the suggestion.